# Shiny: Make renderUI react to drop-down list not submitButton

Tags: r, shiny

How do I get renderUI to react to the user selecting different values from a drop-down list without having to click on my submitButton?

I've got a wellPanel that contains 3 things:
1) My drop-down list
2) A set of dynamic inputs (created by my renderUI function, depend on selection in #1)
3) submitButton

Desired behavior: Changes to the drop-down selection give the user different input widgets to use. When they are ready for the results of their selected inputs, they click the submitButton, and they get their results in the mainPanel.

Problem: My renderUI only reacts to the drop-down selection after clicking the submitButton. As far as I can tell, I need to isolate something or use observeEvent, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Simplified example:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

ui  <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
column(4,wellPanel(
  selectInput("analysis", label = "Type of Analysis:", 
              c("Award Total" = "total", 
                "Award Average" = "average"),
              width = validateCssUnit("70%")),
  uiOutput("filter_box"),
  submitButton()
    )),
column(8, textOutput("sample_text"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output$filter_box <- renderUI({
if(input$analysis == "total"){
  tagList(radioButtons(inputId = "input1", label = "Select One:",c("A", "B", "C"), selected = "A"))
} else {
  tagList(checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "input2", label = "Select all that apply:",c("1","2","3","4","5")),
          dateRangeInput(inputId = "input3", label = "Enter Date Range"))
}
})

output$sample_text <- renderText({
  if(input$analysis == "total"){
    input$input1
  } else if(input$analysis == "average") {
    c(input$input2, input$input3)
  }
 })
}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: You need to not use submitButton, and use an actionButton instead. submitButtons are terrible (shiny authors themselves recommend against it) because they result in strange reactive behaviour. Sorry I'm not going to give you a solution, I just suggest you use actionButton instead, and this problem won't happen then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to introduce two changes.

1. Change the `submitButton` to an `actionButton` (see comment from @daattali)
2. Isolate `renderText`, and make it reactive to the actionButton.

See code below.

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

ui  <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4,wellPanel(
      selectInput("analysis", label = "Type of Analysis:", 
                  c("Award Total" = "total", 
                    "Award Average" = "average"),
                  width = validateCssUnit("70%")),
      uiOutput("filter_box"),
      actionButton(inputId = 'button_1',label = 'Apply Changes')
    )),
    column(8, textOutput("sample_text"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output$filter_box <- renderUI({
    if(input$analysis == "total"){
      tagList(radioButtons(inputId = "input1", label = "Select One:",c("A", "B", "C"), selected = "A"))
    } else {
      tagList(checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "input2", label = "Select all that apply:",c("1","2","3","4","5")),
              dateRangeInput(inputId = "input3", label = "Enter Date Range"))
    }
  })

  output$sample_text <- renderText({
    input$button_1
    isolate({
      if(input$analysis == "total"){
        input$input1
      } else if(input$analysis == "average") {
        c(input$input2, input$input3)
      }
    })

  })
}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: That's great, thank you. I'm surprised my googling didn't turn up that actionButtons are preferred to submitButtons (thanks @daattali). One additional question: In the renderText for output@sample_text, I take it that input$button_1 is in there to trigger the reactivity, but why doesn't the value of input$button_1 actually get rendered in the resultant text?

Comment: whats is rendered is the what is returned by the renderText() function. In this case since there is no return() statement, that would be the last statement executed (here this is conditional on the if/else). You may use return() to make this more explicit.